# Is it possible to add arrows heads on poly line using Android maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How to draw poly line with arrow head(It indicates the direction) using Android Maps V2 API. In [Android Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions) this option is not available.Is it possible to add arrows on polyline?

Comment: Is it possible to add arrows heads on polyline using Android maps v2. How to do this? any link?

Comment: you mean to track down the route right!!!

Comment: yes.I have multiple locations and I want to connect these locations and display as route using poly line with arrows.

Comment: Is it possible to add arrow on poly line using Android maps v2 API?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a working example I've developed using the same concept as what Doug suggested, by taking a JavaScript example (http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_arrows.htm) and converting it to Java code. For handiness it uses images from Google Maps servers, but these could images of your design or could be scraped off the web and stored locally in the app. I'm downloading these on main thread for sake of demonstration, but don't do that if using in a live app!!

The key difference to the JavaScript example though is that you have to project the arrow head image onto a larger image four times the size, working out where to translate the image to based on the bearing from A to B, and finally center that image over the existing B marker by adding another anchored marker with your larger image for an icon.

Firstly add your polylines:

```
PolylineOptions polylines = new PolylineOptions();

LatLng from = new LatLng(f.getLatitude(), f.getLongitude());
LatLng to = new LatLng(t.getLatitude(), t.getLongitude());

polylines.add(from, to).color(polyColor).width(2);

mMap.addPolyline(polylines);

DrawArrowHead(mMap, from, to);
```

Then add your arrow heads:

```
private final double degreesPerRadian = 180.0 / Math.PI;

private void DrawArrowHead(GoogleMap mMap, LatLng from, LatLng to){
    // obtain the bearing between the last two points
    double bearing = GetBearing(from, to);

    // round it to a multiple of 3 and cast out 120s
    double adjBearing = Math.round(bearing / 3) * 3;
    while (adjBearing >= 120) {
        adjBearing -= 120;
    }

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    // Get the corresponding triangle marker from Google        
    URL url;
    Bitmap image = null;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/dir_" + String.valueOf((int)adjBearing) + ".png");
        try {
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (image != null){

        // Anchor is ratio in range [0..1] so value of 0.5 on x and y will center the marker image on the lat/long
        float anchorX = 0.5f;
        float anchorY = 0.5f;

        int offsetX = 0;
        int offsetY = 0;

        // images are 24px x 24px
        // so transformed image will be 48px x 48px

        //315 range -- 22.5 either side of 315
        if (bearing >= 292.5 && bearing < 335.5){
            offsetX = 24;
            offsetY = 24;
        }
        //270 range
        else if (bearing >= 247.5 && bearing < 292.5){
            offsetX = 24;
            offsetY = 12;
        }
        //225 range
        else if (bearing >= 202.5 && bearing < 247.5){
            offsetX = 24;
            offsetY = 0;
        }
        //180 range
        else if (bearing >= 157.5 && bearing < 202.5){
            offsetX = 12;
            offsetY = 0;
        }
        //135 range
        else if (bearing >= 112.5 && bearing < 157.5){
            offsetX = 0;
            offsetY = 0;
        }
        //90 range
        else if (bearing >= 67.5 && bearing < 112.5){
            offsetX = 0;
            offsetY = 12;
        }
        //45 range
        else if (bearing >= 22.5 && bearing < 67.5){
            offsetX = 0;
            offsetY = 24;
        }
        //0 range - 335.5 - 22.5
        else {
            offsetX = 12;
            offsetY = 24;
        }

        Bitmap wideBmp;
        Canvas wideBmpCanvas;
        Rect src, dest;

        // Create larger bitmap 4 times the size of arrow head image
        wideBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth() * 2, image.getHeight() * 2, image.getConfig());

        wideBmpCanvas = new Canvas(wideBmp); 

        src = new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        dest = new Rect(src); 
        dest.offset(offsetX, offsetY); 

        wideBmpCanvas.drawBitmap(image, src, dest, null);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(to)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(wideBmp))
        .anchor(anchorX, anchorY));
    }
}

private double GetBearing(LatLng from, LatLng to){
    double lat1 = from.latitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
    double lon1 = from.longitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
    double lat2 = to.latitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
    double lon2 = to.longitude * Math.PI / 180.0;

    // Compute the angle.
    double angle = - Math.atan2( Math.sin( lon1 - lon2 ) * Math.cos( lat2 ), Math.cos( lat1 ) * Math.sin( lat2 ) - Math.sin( lat1 ) * Math.cos( lat2 ) * Math.cos( lon1 - lon2 ) );

    if (angle < 0.0)
        angle += Math.PI * 2.0;

    // And convert result to degrees.
    angle = angle * degreesPerRadian;

    return angle;
}
```

Comment: If you did have the images downloaded and in your app, you could do something like this instead:


`int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier("dir_" + String.valueOf((int)adjBearing), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
     Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), identifier);`

Comment: Also, if you were to scrape the images off the net and put them in your drawable folder, make sure to put them in a `drawable-nodpi` folder so they don't get scaled up for the screen density!

Comment: Andddd... disable map gesture rotation, as the arrows won't rotate with the map!
`Map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);`

Comment: I felt obligated to put -1, because there is no excuse for doing a network request on main thread. Also the input stream is not closed.

Answer (score 4):

As of [Feb. 15, 2017 release of Android Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#february_15_2017) you can now add custom [Line caps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#line-caps) to the end of polylines on Android Maps API v2, which can be arrows.

From the [Line caps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#styling-shapes) documentation:

> The following snippet specifies a custom bitmap for the end cap:
>
> ```
> mPolyline.setEndCap(
>         new CustomCap(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow),
>                 16));
> ```
>
> When you use a custom bitmap, you should specify a reference stroke width in pixels. The API scales the bitmap accordingly. The reference stroke width is the stroke width that you used when designing the bitmap image for the cap, at the original dimension of the image. The default reference stroke width is 10 pixels. Hint: To determine the reference stroke width, open your bitmap image at 100% zoom in an image editor, and plot the desired width of the line stroke relative to the image.
>
> If you use [`BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory#fromResource(int)) to create the bitmap, make sure you use a density-independent resource ([nodpi](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)).

The post from Google for the related resolved issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822534#comment11) says:

> We have added the ability to customize the start and end caps of Polylines with a custom bitmap. Using this you will be able to add arrowheads to your Polylines.
>
> See information about Line Caps in the Shapes Guide here: 
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#line_caps
>
> See an example in the new Polylines and Polygons tutorial here: 
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_custom_styling_to_your_polyline
>
> See the release notes here: 
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#february_15_2017
>
> See the blog post here: 
>   https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/02/styling-and-custom-data-for-polylines.html

Comment: Hi
Can you give an exampe of arrow image
I'm interested in direction of it N, S, W or E e.g?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this but I think that it should be possible by using markers.  You will need to create a series of, say 20, small arrows each pointing in different directions, 18, 36, 54 degrees etc.  Then either when constructing the polyline or, probably better, as a separate process after the polyline has been built, run through all of the coordinates at whatever spacing you want and, at each chosen point get the bearing using locationn.getbearing and, from that bearing, determine which directional arrow to use as a marker and lay the appropriate marker at that point