# Android maps trace a route with symbols

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to do this map in android, but i cant find a way for draw a polygon with icons and take the direction automatically

[image]

This the code using javascript that i need to write in Java:

```
var lineSymbol = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
};
lineas = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: ruta,
    map: GMap,
    icons: [{
        icon: lineSymbol,
        repeat:'60px',
        offset: '50%'
    }],
    strokeColor: color,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    geodesic:true
});
```

Comment: I think you can use draw a list of `PolylineOptions` which configured the Arrow you need, For more details, please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android).

Comment: The problem is not drawing the polyline, the problem is add the symbol with a rotation for the direction.

Comment: I think you can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18251754/4186942).